# error in open cv file in 'haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml

Tags: runtime-error

> my file not opening [enter image description here**your tex[ERROR:0@4.699] global persistence.cpp:519 cv::FileStorage::Impl::open Can't open file: 'haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml' in read modet**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mu484.jpg)

[ERROR:0@4.699] global persistence.cpp:519 cv::FileStorage::Impl::open Can't open file: 'haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml' in read mode